# AngularJS - How to go to .config() from a function

Tags: angularjs, authentication, controller

I'm newbie about AngularJS. I'm doing a simple login form with my angular function like this.

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http)
{

    $scope.doLogin = function(){

         $http.get('pages/login.php?userid='+$scope.userid+'&userpassword='+$scope.password)
         .success(function(data) {

            if(data === 'F'){
                $scope.message = 'Invalid username or password!';
            } else  {
                $scope.message = 'Logged succesfully!';
                // i think should goes here...
            }

        });

     };

}
```

When the login is successfull, i need to call my controller in this:

```
userMg.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/auth', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/auth.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl'
      }).
      when('/usercp/:user_id', {
         templateUrl: 'pages/usercp.html',
         controller: 'UserCpCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/auth'
      });
  }]);
```

Comment: Are you trying to route to a different location? If so, use the $route service.

Comment: Dude, excuse... How can i use it ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the location service if you are trying to redirect.

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http, $location)
{

    $scope.doLogin = function(){

         $http.get('pages/login.php?userid='+$scope.userid+'&userpassword='+$scope.password)
         .success(function(data) {

            if(data === 'F'){
                $scope.message = 'Invalid username or password!';
            } else  {
                $scope.message = 'Logged succesfully!';
                var userId = data.userId;
                // RE-DIRECT HERE
                $location.path('/usercp/' + userId);
            }

        });

     };

}
```